# Nullpointer on Removing Animated View from Framelayout

Tags: android, animation, nullpointerexception, imageview

I've got an ImageView in a class extending AnimationSet. The ImageView is animated and should be removed afterwards.

This is the class where the stuff takes place:

```
public class TrackerAnimation extends AnimationSet {

private ImageView imageView;
private FrameLayout context_layout;

/** Constructor
* context = Activity
* context_layout = Framelayout in which the ImageView will be added programmatically
*
*/
public TrackerAnimation(Context context, FrameLayout context_layout, ...){
    //...
    this.imageView = new ImageView(context);
    this.context_layout.addView(imageView);

    this.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        TrackerAnimation.this.onAnimationStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        TrackerAnimation.this.onAnimationEnd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void start() {
    imageView.startAnimation(animationSet);
}

// Invoked by the AnimationListener, created at Constructor
public void onAnimationStart() {
    //empty
}

// Invoked by the AnimationListener, created at Constructor
public void onAnimationEnd() {
    // ! context_layout and imageView are both NOT NULL at this point
    this.context_layout.removeView(imageView);
}
}
```

If the user presses a button in the Activity an instance of TrackerAnimation is created and started. When the Animation is finished the AnimationListener invokes onAnimationEnd() of TrackerAnimation (yeah.. it has the same name as the Interface Method of AnimationListener).

If you press the Button two times in a row and the first Animation is still running, then the App crashes with the following Message:

```
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046): Process: com.abc.def, PID: 5046
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3197)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
09-01 18:42:08.678: E/AndroidRuntime(5046):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
```

Since there is no further hint what is going wrong inside the VM I dont know how to search a solution for this problem. I cannot even debug, because it seems to be very hard to simulate an doubleClick while Debugging.

Inside the layout.xml there is a nested Framelayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_tracker"
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="120sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_tracker" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_my_location"
        android:layout_width="90sp"
        android:layout_height="90sp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_my_location" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_map_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The inner FrameLayout with the id "fl_map_overlay" is the one the ViewImages goes to. And they should be removed from it too via the callback-stuff I showed above.

An early attempt was to manage the ImageView as a WeakReference... but I guess this does not really solve the problem of that Nullpointer.

I appreciate any help!

Edit: Hardcoded Variables in XML are bad... I know it ;D

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I use an invisible button area now and animate the icon "handy". Its not that comfortable but it works.